# Errors using pacstrap on install

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, system-installation

I’m installing Arch Linux for the first time. I didn’t encounter any problems during setup until I had to perform the actual installation with `pacstrap`.

Here’s my input.

```
pacstrap /mnt base base-devel linux linux-firmware vim
```

What I get in return.

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
error: failed retrieving file ‘online-repo.db’ from 192.168.1.156:8000 : Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds.
error: failed to update online-repo. (download library error)
error: failed to synchronize all databases
==>ERROR: Failed to install packages to new root
```

I am able to ping archlinux.org and google.com without any issue, but not the ip mentioned in the error. I have heard that having `timedate-ctl` setup incorrectly can mess up sync, so I changed it to the correct time and timezone manually. I tried using `reflector` several times with different protocols and locations but I still get the same errors. I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have a proxy server configured, and pacstrap tries to retrive the packages from it, which should in turn communicate with the actual mirrors and get the packages for you.

The `192.168.1.156:8000` is a local address (address of a device on your wifi or wired network). You probably typed something like `export http_proxy=192.168.1.156:8000`, so make sure the proxy is up, or run the command without a proxy server, so that you communicate directly with mirrors.

Running the following command may solve your problem (if you dont want to reboot and restart the installation):

```bsh
unset http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy rsync_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY RSYNC_PROXY
```

This will remove all proxy servers you configured during the installation.

Another thing I would like to say; ask all questions regarding arch linux on [arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org), it is more likely to get help there for problems specific to arch linux.

Comment: I ran that command but still got the same errors. I don’t recall ever setting up a proxy. Thanks for the suggestion, I’ll probably post there as well.

Comment: @GlitchyGoats i hope you already solved the problem, but if not, then i can help you if you provide the instructions you were following while installing the system, and show the output of `printenv` and `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.7/Python-3.8.7.tar.xz` commands before you attempt to pacstrap.